# Linq Group by 6 Categories and Person

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I need help to construct a linq query  to display payments grouped into categories which could be filtered by Year, Month and Member Name

I have these models

```
Member(MemberId,MemberName)
Payment(PayId, MemberId[foreignkey], PayDate, Amount,CategoryId[foreignkey])
Category(CategoryId, CategoryName}
```

Looking at getting an output like below
John could have made two different payments for the same category for the month of April (04) and such payments are added together (sum)

```
Name  Year Month   Cat1     Cat2    Cat3    Cat4   Cat5    Cat6
John  2016  04     12.30    0.00    30.60   15.20  120.00  15.40
Fred  2016  04     10.30    22.50   80.60   0.00   100.00  19.40
```

I have tried using joins but my real life application has 25 Payment categories
and joining the same table for 25 times exceeds MYSQL permissible sub selects on the production server.

I will be happy to receive direction on the best way to achieve this

Comment: Do you want this grouped by the user name and the year and the month (i.e. display rows for `John 2016 04` and `John 2016 03` and `John 2015 12` etc, or just grouped by user name and filtered for a specific month and year?

Comment: grouped by user name and filtered for a specific month and year

Comment: OK, No time just now, but will add an answer in about an hour.

Comment: Apologies, did not get time and it will now be a few more hours (but the starting point is to use `db.Payment.GroupBy(x => new { member = x.MemberId, category = c.CategoryId });` for the grouping which will then need to be projected into a view model representing your view).

Comment: I appreciate your concern to help please do help when you are able

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indicated in the comments that you want to filter my Month/Year so there seems no need to include those columns in the table and instead you could use a heading for the table, say "Results for April 2016".

Start by defining view models to represent want you want to display in the view

```
public class MemberPaymentVM // for the table rows
{
    public MemberPaymentVM(int categoryCount)
    {
        Amounts = new List<decimal>(new decimal[categoryCount]);
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Amounts { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
public class MonthPaymentsVM
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM yyyy}"]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<MemberPaymentVM> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

The following queries can be chained, but to break this into each component, first filter the data

```
var date = new DateTime(2016, 4, 1);
var filtered = db.Payments.Where(x => x.PayDate >= date && x.PayDate < date.AddMonths(1));
```

Then group the data by both `Member` and `Category` and sum the results (I'm assuming that your `Payment` model contains virtual properties for the relationships

```
var grouped = filtered.GroupBy(x => new { member = x.Member.ID, category = x.Category.ID }).Select(x => new
{
    Member = x.First().Member,
    Category = x.First().Category,
    Amount = x.Sum(y => y.Amount)
});
```

Then group again by `Member` to represent each table row

```
var data = grouped.GroupBy(x => x.Member.ID);
```

Next, get your categories

```
var categories = db.Categories;
var categoryCount = categories.Count();
var categoryIDs = categories.Select(x => x.CategoryId).ToList();
```

And the build you view models

```
var model = new MonthPaymentsVM()
{
    Date = date,
    Categories = categories.Select(x => x.CategoryName),
    Payments = new List<MemberPaymentVM>()
};
foreach(var group in data)
{
    MemberPaymentVM payment = new MemberPaymentVM categoryCount);
    payment.Name = group.First().Member.Name;
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        int index = categoryIDs.IndexOf(item.Category.CategoryId);
        payment.Amounts[index] = item.Amount;
        payment.Total += item.Amount;
    }
    model.Payments.Add(payment);
}
```

and finally, return the model to the view

```
return View(model);
```

And in the view

```
@model MonthPaymentsVM
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Date);
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            @foreach(var category in Model.Categories)
            {
                <td>@category</td>
            }
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Payments)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                @foreach (var amount in item.Amounts)
                {
                    <td>@amount</td> // @amount.ToString("c") to format it
                }
                <td>@item.Total</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks I am getting this error at  var Categories =db.Categories(); Error 38 Non-invocable member  cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Change it to `var categoryIDs = categories.Select(x => x.CategoryId).ToList();` (see edit)

Comment: This is working prety well, I had to change First() to FirstOrDefault. One last request how can i get s total for all the payments at the last column and also if I have any other property in the members model and I want to include in a column how do i go about that? Thanks very much for this rescue

Comment: Sure, both are easy enough. I'll update the answer shortly with the row total, but a bit hard to give you advice on the second one without seeing your models.

Comment: Thanks like if I want to show the memberId  in addition to name.  Also I have  noticed that if a particular person makes  payments on different dates in the same month it ignors the others and picks the first one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108740/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-diin).

Comment: I  have modified the code to group per transactionId instead of user which is working great.  I now want to only display  payment categories which have payment to them and their amounts whilst keeping everything else the same. Can you please give me a guide?

Comment: Your going to have to ask a new question (this answer is to long as it is), and I'm not sure what you mean by `transactionId` (there is no field by that name in your question)

Comment: I have put the new question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579602/linq-query-to-group-payment-receipts-for-a-person-over-a-period